# Calling a stored procedure for each row in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to call a stored proc in a loop for each record in a query.

Here's what I have now:

```
WITH X AS (  
SELECT customerid FROM DBcustomers  
)  
WHILE(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM X))  
BEGIN  
    SELECT TOP 1 @Id = customerid FROM X  
    EXEC [dbo].[AnotherSP] @Id , 1
    DELETE FROM X WHERE customerid = @Id  
END
```

, but this does not compile.

Comment: What is this supposed to be?

Comment: This will perform an update operation on all rows- (wanted to implement for loop)

Comment: You cannot do what you're trying to do - hence errors. You don't need loops, but if you want - look up cursor

Comment: Pls check my edit now. This is what I want to perform.

Comment: I want to execute the other Store Proc. in that while loop.

Comment: It's best to avoid loops in SQL when you can, the language (and implementing dbs) tend to be designed the other direction.  Can you not call the proc as part of a regular statement?  ie `SELECT proc(customerId, 1) FROM DBCustomers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to do UPDATE like this:

```
UPDATE ProductTable SET IsActive = 1 
  WHERE customerid  IN (SELECT customerid FROM DBcustomers)
```

or for your edited question use cursors:

```
DECLARE @id BIG
DECLARE Customers CURSOR 
FOR SELECT customerid FROM DBcustomers 

OPEN Customers FETCH NEXT FROM Customers INTO @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   EXEC [dbo].[AnotherSP] @id , 1
   FETCH NEXT FROM Customers INTO @id
END
CLOSE Customers
DEALLOCATE Customers
```

Comment: Pls check my edit now. This is what I want to perform.

Comment: I want to execute the other Store Proc. in that while loop.

Comment: Actually I was not in favor of using CURSOR but this will work for what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  productTable
SET     isActive = 1
WHERE   customerId IN
        (
        SELECT  customerId
        FROM    dbCustomers
        )
```

**Update:**

```
DECLARE cr_customer CURSOR
FOR
SELECT  customerId
FROM    dbCustomers

DECLARE @id INT

FETCH   NEXT
FROM    cr_customer
INTO    @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        EXEC anotherSP @id , 1
        FETCH   NEXT
        FROM    cr_customer
        INTO    @id
END

CLOSE   cr_customer

DEALLOCATE
        cr_customer
```

Comment: Pls check my edit now. This is what I want to perform.

Comment: I want to execute the other Store Proc. in that while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do it:

```
DECLARE @Id INT;
SELECT TOP 1 @Id = customerid FROM DBcustomers ORDER BY customerid;
WHILE @Id IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN  
    EXEC [dbo].[AnotherSP] @Id, 1;
    DECLARE @LastId INT;
    SELECT @LastId = @Id;
    SELECT @Id = NULL;
    SELECT @Id = customerid FROM DBcustomers WHERE customerId > @LastId ORDER BY customerid;
END;
```